# AdvancedDataGrid: dataTip = headerText

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tooltip, advanceddatagrid

I have a pretty straightforward question which google fails to give me the answer to :

I have an AdvancedDataGrid where i build the columns dynamically (variable number of columns) in ActionScript, and i want the dataTip to display the column headerText when the user hovers over a cell. Adobe's example dataTipFunction:

```
  private function tipFunc(value:Object):String
  {
      if (value is AdvancedDataGridColumn)
          return "Column Name";

      // Use the 'name' property of the data provider element.
      return "Name: " + value["name"];
  }
```

But in this case the value is only an AdvancedDataGrid column if the user hovers over a column header? I want the dataTip to always show the headerText for that column. So if i have to use this function, then how do i get the column headerText for a cell?

And as i understand the *dataTipField* i can't really use it to statically equal column.headerText (dataTipField = headerText).

Anyone have any pointers on how i can achieve this? It seems like a really easy task, still i can't seem to find out how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different function per column, which could be anonymous:

```
<AdvancedDataGridColumn dataTipFunction="{function(value:Object):String{return 'Data Tip'}}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks m8! That worked like a charm.
column.showDataTips = true;    column.dataTipFunction=function(value:Object):String{return headerText};